# Unable to JSON.Parse any string with httpRequest

Tags: json, parse-platform

I have my own webservice which I make POST request from a Parse Job feature.

Few days ago I was perfectly able to `Parse()` the JSON, now I get a bunch of **[object Object]** and **undefined** properties. I dind't change anything on my webservice, I even tried to rollback but none seems to work.

What my code look like:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://MYWEBSERVICE.php',
      body: {
        userTia: jsoncontent,
        userPass: jsoncontent,
        userUnidade: jsoncontent
      },
      success: function(httpResponse) {
        console.log(httpResponse.text);
        var tiaJsonParsed = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
        console.log("Response: " + httpResponse.text);
        console.log("JsonParsed: " + tiaJsonParsed[1]);
        console.log("JsonParsed: " + tiaJsonParsed[1].nome)
      },
      error: function(httpResponse) {
        console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
      }
    });
```

The `httpResponse.text` gives me a valid JSON, exactly what I expect. But all those console.logs gives me:

```
[object Object]; 1: [object Object]; 2: [object Object]; 3: [object Object]; 4: [object Object]; 5: [object Object]; 6: [object Object]; 7: [object Object];
```

Yeah its right, it's an array with objects, this is correct. But shouldn't be object Object.

I even have tried:

```
for (var property in tiaJsonParsed) {
   output += property + ': ' + tiaJsonParsed[property]+'; ';
}
console.log('OUTPUT:' + output);
```

Got **undefined** only.

```
var tiaJsonParsed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(httpResponse.data));
var tiaJsonParsed2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(httpResponse.text));
```

It's the same.

So, What I'm doing wrong here? Does Parse.com changed something between this week and last week? Because this suddenly stop and I don't have any more ideas.